# Error while retrieving data from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firstly I'm new on Firebase :)

Here is my code :

```
    package com.denizkaanyilmaz.cikmissorular;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.security.acl.Group;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://cikmissorular-31da2.firebaseio.com/Sinav-01");

        ref.addValueEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                System.out.println(snapshot.getValue());

                for (com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    sinav post = postSnapshot.getValue(sinav.class);
                    System.out.println(post.getIsim() + " - " + post.getYil());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What I try to do here is simple I just want to get that data as string.
This line gives me error--> sinav post = postSnapshot.getValue(sinav.class);

Here is my sinav java file :

```
package com.denizkaanyilmaz.cikmissorular;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Denizkaan on 18.12.2017.
 */

public class sinav {

    public String Isim;
    public String Yil;
    public List<Soru> sorular;


    public sinav() {
    }

    public String getIsim() {
        return Isim;
    }

    public String getYil() {
        return Yil;
    }

    public List<Soru> getSorular() {
        return sorular;
    }
}
```

and here is my firebase:
[image: Firebase]

When I delete the child's named Soru01 and Soru02 or replace them with string I can retrieve the data but when it's like this I can't get the data. I try to fill my ListView with Sinav-01, Sinav-02, Sinav-03 on Acticity load but have issues to get the data, can someone help please?
Thank you

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the name of `Soru01` and `Soru02`, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference sorularRef = rootRef.child("Sinav-01").child("Sorular");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.getKey();
            Log.d("TAG", name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
sorularRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
Soru01
Soru02
```

Comment: First thank you it worked, can you explain where was my mistake on my codes? I saw a lot of codes with the ref I use and many with the one that you use. Which one is right? typing FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); or other one?